# Run simple swift script from terminal with imported library

Tags: swift, import, terminal

I would like to migrate some python code to swift which includes numpy and found a library called Matft.

I'm doing this on a VM and Xcode is very slow, so it would be great to avoid that and use the terminal (ideally run the .swift from a shared folder), but than I got the error: "no such module".
I found that I could pass -I flag and specify a path for the lib, but does not working for me.

Can someone give an easy explanation how to import external library in such situation?